# ASP.NET Core - The name 'JsonRequestBehavior' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

In my ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) project, I'm getting above error on my following Controller Action method. What I may be missing? Or, are there any work arounds?:

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CountryLookup()
    {
        var countries = new List<SearchTypeAheadEntity>
        {
            new SearchTypeAheadEntity {ShortCode = "US", Name = "United States"},
            new SearchTypeAheadEntity {ShortCode = "CA", Name = "Canada"}
        };
        
        return Json(countries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Please note folowing comments from  @NateBarbettini below:

1. `JsonRequestBehavior` has been deprecated in ASP.NET Core 1.0.
2. In accepted response from @Miguel below, the `return type` of action method `does not` specifically need to be of type JsonResult. ActionResult or IActionResult works too.

Comment: look at the documentation for [JsonRequestBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior(v=vs.118).aspx).  the __Namespace__ is what you need to put after your `using` statement at the top of your file, and the __Assembly__ is what you have to include as a reference to your project.

Comment: @SamIam Thank you for the MSDN link. I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0 (.NET Framework) project template that does not seem to have System.Web.MVC assembly available when I search Reference-->Add dialog box. Any suggestion or workaround?

Comment: @nam AFAIK, `JsonRequestBehavior` has been deprecated in ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Returning Json-formatted data:

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult CountryLookup()
    {
         var countries = new List<SearchTypeAheadEntity>
         {
             new SearchTypeAheadEntity {ShortCode = "US", Name = "United States"},
             new SearchTypeAheadEntity {ShortCode = "CA", Name = "Canada"}
         };

         return Json(countries);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't specifically need to have a return type of `JsonResult`. `ActionResult` or `IActionResult` works too.

Comment: @NateBarbettini Thank you. I've added your comments in an additional `UPDATE` section of my post.

Comment: because JsonResult implements ActionResult :)

Answer (score 12):

In Code it's replace To `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` with `new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()`

It's Work same as `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult CountryLookup()
  {
    var countries = new List<SearchTypeAheadEntity>
        {
            new SearchTypeAheadEntity {ShortCode = "US", Name = "United States"},
            new SearchTypeAheadEntity {ShortCode = "CA", Name = "Canada"}
        };

    return Json(countries, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some times you need to return a message back in JSON, simply use the JSON result as below, no need for jsonrequestbehavior any more, below simple code to use:

```
public ActionResult DeleteSelected([FromBody]List<string> ids)
{
    try
    {
        if (ids != null && ids.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                bool done = new tblCodesVM().Delete(Convert.ToInt32(id));
                
            }
            return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Deleted Scussefully" });

        }
        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Nothing Selected" });
    }
    catch (Exception dex)
    {
        
        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = dex.Message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello as accepted answer in controller you dont have to say

```
return Json(countries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

just write

```
return Json(countries);
```

But in cshtml in ajax you should call your entity properties staring with lower case i.g.:**s**hortCode and **n**ame.

```
$.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: `/ClientController/CountryLookup`
            }).done(function (result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        var shortCode=result[i].shortCode;
                        var name= result[i].name;
                }

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been porting a website from asp.net to asp.net Core. I replaced:
`return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
with
`Json(data, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions());`
and everything started working again.