# prepend a string in all responses within ASP.NET core json

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I would like to prepend all JSON responses with following string:

```
)]}',\n
```

What is the best way to achieve this with ASP.NET Core? I would like to have it enabled for all JSON responses automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49189185/11683

Comment: Just curious: why ? SHouldn't the proper json syntax be produced by a library (typically json.net) ? Why manipulating json string ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/security#xssi

Comment: So you want to prevent [json hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2669690/11683). It may already [not be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16289894/11683). The idiomatic ASP.NET MVC way to protect from it was [JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8464677/11683), which [was removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578463/asp-net-core-the-name-jsonrequestbehavior-does-not-exist-in-the-current-cont#comment66001613_38578463) from MVC Core, apparently because it is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Middleware that checks the following condition (or whatever condition you need).

`if(context.Response.ContentType == "application/json")`

Then you just <s>append</s> prepend the context.Response.Body with your string.