# The GET request call returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to call my WEB API in .NET Core from the jQuery like below:

```
[HttpGet("GetText")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetText()
{
    try
    {
        string welCome = "Test";

        JsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        return Json(welCome, JsonSettings);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And the jQuery caller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller/GetText?callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert('Success -> ' + JSON.stringify(data.statusText)); 
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Error -> ' + JSON.stringify(data.statusText)); 
        }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

The API is calling successfully but it seems it will then redirect to error function in my Ajax and show the error alert with a "success" as it's `statusText`. I mean this: **Error -> "Success"** I am not sure why this happens?

**I would like to print `welCome` as a success result and in the alert command.**

Also please note that I am calling this API from another project, I mean the jQuery's AJAX code is inside another project. I am not sure if it is important or not at all.

The jQuery's AJAX Caller path: `file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Path/index.html`

The API's address: `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ThisProject\MyAPI`

And the URL of this API: url: "http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller/GetText",

Comment: its expecting to recieve a json object, you are sending a string back

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier So, shouldn't `return Json` return a json?

Comment: Remove `?callback=?` will work. You will see it sends an `option` request first and then send a `get` request in dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try the C# Code in the following manner :

```
[HttpGet("GetText")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetText()
{
    try
    {
        string welCome = "Test";    
        return Ok(new { message = welCome });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Try the Jquery Code in the following manner :

```
$.ajax({
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: 'json',
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller/GetText',
       success: function (response) {
       alert('Success' + response.message);
      },
      failure: function (response) {

      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But nothing still has changed, I don't still get the `alert('Success' + response.message);` in the success function, however as I said my API is running successfully.

Comment: Also the `?callback=?` is necessary and should be appended after my url because without it the method of the request in the brwoser is shown as `OPTION` instead of `GET`.

Comment: Just this part is executed after API call `error: function (data) {
                alert('Error -> ' + JSON.stringify(data.statusText)); 
            }` also the return status is 200.

Comment: May be you are experiencing CORS error. Make sure you have configured your CORS.

Comment: What is CORS? How can I configure it?

Comment: Are you sure that `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is working in .NET Core? Because this won't compile in .NET Core.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578463/asp-net-core-the-name-jsonrequestbehavior-does-not-exist-in-the-current-cont

Comment: You can  return Ok(new { message = welCome });

Comment: No the result is still the same. I am really wondering why the last block of this three statements is executed, the main problem is that. `success: function (response) {
                    alert('Success' + response.message);
                },
                failure: function (response) {

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Error -> ' + JSON.stringify(data.statusText)); 
                }`